# How do i modify a constructor?

Tags: java

I am very new to java and am trying to figure out how to modify a constructor to create a BankAccount object that stores a monthly interest when the user inputs an annual interest rate of the format? I am clueless, any thoughts? also, the BankAccount constructor stored a monthly interest rate for the BankAccount object's instance field originally, but the annual rate needs to convert to a monthly rate. So how do i switch this around?

```
/**
 * BankAccount class
 * This class simulates a bank account.
 *
 * (Taken from "Starting Out with Java - Early Objects 
 * (Third Edition) by Tony Gaddis, 2008 by Pearson Educ.)
 * 
 */

public class BankAccount {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
    private double balance;    // Account balance
    private double interestRate; // Interest rate
    private double interest;   // Interest earned

    /**
     * The constructor initializes the balance
     * and interestRate fields with the values
     * passed to startBalance and intRate. The
     * interest field is assigned to 0.0.
     */

    public BankAccount(double startBalance, double intRate)
    {
        balance = startBalance;
        interestRate = intRate;
        interest = 0.0; 
    } 

    /**
     * The deposit method adds the parameter
     * amount to the balance field.
     */

    public void deposit(double amount)
    {
        balance += amount;
    }

    /**
     * The withdraw method subtracts the 
     * parameter amount from the balance 
     * field.
     */

    public void withdraw(double amount)
    {
        balance -= amount;
    }

    /**
     * The addInterest method adds the interest 
     * for the month to the balance field.
     */

    public void addInterest()
    {
        interest = balance * interestRate;
        balance += interest;
    }

    /** 
     * The getBalance method returns the 
     * value in the balance field.
     */

    public double getBalance()
    {
        return balance;
    }

    /**
     * The getInterest method returns the
     * value in the interest field.
     */

    public double getInterest()
    {
        return interest;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what you need.  You have a constructor that accepts an interest rate and stores it, so why do you want to modify it?  If the constructor's interest rate is monthly, and the user inputs a yearly rate, the caller who uses `new BankAccount` should be the one to divide by 12, not the `BankAccount` constructor.

Comment: the BankAccount constructor stored a monthly interest rate for the BankAccount object's instance field originally, but the annual rate needs to convert to a monthly rate (i.e., 1.5 to 0.00125) thank you for the feedback.

Comment: I think ajb is wondering why you don't just use 0.00125?

Answer (score 0):

You can create any number of constructers in java , method name has to be  class name

```
public BankAccount(double startBalance, double intRate,float interest )
{
balance = startBalance;
interestRate = intRate;
interest = 0.0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

//Modify the BankAccount constructor this way.

```
public BankAccount(double startBalance, double intRate)
{
    balance = startBalance;
    interestRate = (intRate)/(12*100);
    interest = 0.0;
}
```